# Simplify the expression of eigensolution by wxmaxima

Tags: complex-numbers, maxima, simplify, eigenvalue

By chance, I met this strange situation described below.

The stiffness matrix **K** and mass matrix **M** are given as:

> K:matrix([141,-39,9],[-39,21,9],[9,9,21]);
>
> M:matrix([1.5,0,0],[0,0.5,0],[0,0,0.5]);

The eigenvalues is then found by:

> eig:eigenvalues(invert(M).K);

They are all real.

However, if I change the mass matrix **M** to, something like:

> M:matrix([2,0,0],[0,0.5,0],[0,0,0.5]);

or, even:

> M:matrix([1.51,0,0],[0,0.5,0],[0,0,0.5]);

or, else:

> M:matrix([1.499,0,0],[0,0.5,0],[0,0,0.5]);

then, the obtained eigenvalues are not real anymore (strange thing).

I also tried to simplify the obtained results (using simp, ratsimp, fullratsimp, demoivre), but I failed to transform the obtained eigenvalues (expressions with complex numbers) into real ones.

Could please you kindly help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Supplement information: Solving with GNU Octave
K=[141,-39,9;-39,21,9;9,9,21];
M=[2,0,0;0,0.5,0;0,0,0.5];
[eigvec,eigval]=eig(K,M);
gives real eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that the results contain the imaginary unit `%i` but they are not actually complex. I think `float(rectform(eig))` will show imaginary parts which are on the order of the floating point epsilon. You can clean up the output via `rectform` (i.e. return rectangular form rp + i times ip) and `radcan` (i.e. return "canonical" representation of radicals). E.g. `radcan(rectform(eig))`.

If you only need numerical values of eigenvalues, consider using `dgeev` from the add-on package `lapack`. E.g. `load(lapack); dgeev(somematrix);` You can see more info about it via `? dgeev`.

Finally note also that Maxima pretty strongly prefers exact numbers (integers and rationals) in symbolic calculations. So consider applying `ratsimp` to floating point expressions before calling symbolic algorithms such as `eigenvalues`. Maxima will rationalize floats automatically but it might make it clearer if you see the rational form which is the actual input.

Comment: Thank you for your information. By the way, is it reasonable for wxmaxima that it prints out results containing the imaginary unit %i but they are not actually complex?

Comment: Without investigating, my first guess is that the formula for solving the characteristic polynomial is expressed in terms of the imaginary unit, and for most cases with real roots, Maxima can simplify the imaginary part to zero, but in this case the default simplifications are not enough and `radcan` is required. Of course emitting `%i` in real expressions is undesirable.

Comment: Thank you for your further information. Do you have ideas about why just in the case when the mass matrix M is exactly equal to matrix([1.5,0,0],[0,0.5,0],[0,0,0.5]), then wxmaxima outputs real eigenvalues, not seem-to-be complex ones as it does output for other cases. Is there something special for this case?

Comment: One would have to look at the characteristic polynomial of invert(M).K to see what changes. My guess is that as the coefficients change, the algorithm to compute its roots goes down different branches of the code.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that the algorithm should go down different branches, but is it that the branch corresponding to the case of M:matrix([1.5,0,0],[0,0.5,0],[0,0,0.5]) to print out the real eigenvalues is very special? If this matrix is just slightly changed, I don't think, IMHO, that the characteristic polynomial of invert(M).K changes enough to an extent that can switch the computation to another branch.

Comment: Symbolic algorithms often branch depending on whether some quantity is zero or nonzero, and small changes in the parameters of the problem can easily change the quantities on which branches are tested. But exactly what is going on in this problem can only be answered by looking at the characteristic polynomial for the specific cases you have listed.